# What's "jewishness" supposed to mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes, humor

There is an image at http://www.pinterest.com/pin/160511174191029351/ which goes like this:

[image: Cartoon of girl doing math at boardwriting at board and boy behind her. Caption is "Sorry you're intimidated by my Jewishness" (sic, there's no comma)]

I don't quite get the joke... what's "Jewishness" supposed to mean in this context?

Comment: I do not get it either. Clever girl? Not sure how this would be typical

Comment: Meh. I would say this is one of the poorer e-cards.

Comment: "Jewishness" in this context isn't different from its meaning elsewhere: "the state of being Jewish". As far as what the joke might be, note the posters hanging next to the one the girl is working on; they contain the ABC's and some elementary English words which are written left-to-right. The girl, however, is doing long addition/subtraction working from right-to-left which is like Hebrew, the Jewish language. Just a possibility.

Comment: Isn't it possible to make your own 'ecard' using your own words? In which case, everyone can be a comedian ... except the person that did this one.

Comment: I agree. It is not even obvious that the boy is intimidated at all or is pointing out the next step

Comment: I think it is the boy speaking, and the writing and math is irrelevant. But it might be a (very bad) variation of the boy bragging about his manhood.

Comment: @oerkelens Yes, it is not clear who is saying that caption. Is it the girl or the boy who claims they are intimidating by being Jewish?

Comment: I'm with @Frank -- it's probably a single (warped) individual's idea of a joke (or perhaps even an insult -- who knows).  The meaning is even more obscure than a New Yorker cartoon.

Comment: As to "Jewishness", there are a number of stereotypes of what a Jewish person is supposed to be like, from appearance to behavior to handling money to being a mother.  I've rarely found them to be that accurate, but they can be amusing at times (not this one) if you have a reasonably open mind.

Answer (score 3):

In this context it has to do with the stereotype that those of Jewish descent are good with numbers, more specifically sense of money.

Comment: Hmm, not very obvious since it is not even clear if what she does is correct

Comment: I agree, but that's often the case with these images. Various online services have images to which users can apply their own captions. The image is frequently an imperfect match for the sentiment.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an attempt at *wry* humor

> Using or expressing dry, especially mocking, humor

Historically, in many settings, being Jewish was considered negative: it wa a bar to certain occupations, living accomondations, organization membership. It often relegated someone to an isolated neighborhood and exposed them to danger and even death (the Inquisition, the Holocaust).

Generally, *Jewishness* was not an intimidating condition but an intimidated one.

The cited image and text suggests an oxymoron - something that arguably should demean conveys a superior status.

The site from which the card originates is full of such wry images and comments.

Comment: I understand wry humour very well. I am also very well versed in Jewish humour. The answer from Juan makes more sense, but does not make the joke a very convincing one.

Comment: @mplungjan I agree with Juan that the reference probably tries to tap one of the numerous stereotypes attributed to Jews. Like much wry humor, for many people, it doesn't resonate.

Comment: @mplungjan But I can almost hear Myron Cohen making such a statement with his deadpan face (and no numbers in the background).